# Laravel website emulated with Xampp yields: Class "Memcached" not found

Tags: php, apache, xampp, memcached, web-development-server

I copied the content of the public_html folder of the website (generated with Laravel) in the htdocs folder belonging to Xampp. I imported the database on my localhost which includes my login details. I also created the database_connection and the index.php file to connect it to the database. However, when I try to login with my details which work on the "real" website, the localhost gives me this:

FatalThrowableError in MemcachedConnector.php line 51:
Class 'Memcached' not found

I tried for days to follow instructions on the internet (various forums, tutorials, videos) regarding the installation of the Memcached package or various modifications in the Apache config file, but none helped me. Can you also please explain the solution to me in high detail (step by step since I'm an absolute beginner in web development)? In many sources, I found instructions such as: add the following line (but won't specify where) or install this package (but again won't say in which directory and how).

Comment: Did you start the memcached server?

Comment: Did you activate the memcached extension to php

Comment: After installation, I used the command prompt to run it and it says "the memcached service was started successfully". However, it is still not working.

Comment: Did you activate the Memcached extension in `php.ini`

Comment: Can you be more explicit, please? I am not sure what that means.

Comment: PHP meeds an extension to interact with Memcached. It needs adding to the `php.ini` file `extension` set

Comment: extension=php_memcache.dll

[Memcache]
memcache.allow_failover = 1
memcache.max_failover_attempts=20
memcache.chunk_size =8192
memcache.default_port = 11211 


............I added that piece of code after this line: extension=php_ftp.dll

Comment: I downloaded memcached 3.0.4 and it does appear to have a file that contains exactly the Memached class I need. But it has a lot of files I don't know exactly where to extract. Can you guide me into this? There are no instructons and this is really confusing for me. I got it from this place: https://pecl.php.net/package/memcached/3.0.4

Comment: I also added the php_memcache.dll file and I added it to the ext folder, following the instructions from here: https://phpcodez.com/install-memcached-xampp-windows-10/ ......... I also wasn't able to open the memcached.exe file, the console  won't allow me to write anything, but I used the command prompt in the admin mode and I managed to start the server. My localhost is however still giving me the error.

Comment: Are you sure you used the TS (Thread Safe) version of the `php_memcache.dll` and one compiled with a compatible version of the C Compiler that was used to compile you PHP

Comment: I am sorry, I don't know how to find this out.

Comment: Where did you donwnload php_memcache.dll from? And what version of PHP are you running

Comment: I don't know how to find the PHP version, but I downloaded the dll from here: https://codeload.github.com/nono303/PHP7-memcache-dll/zip/master
....I also have a feeling that this is not what I need since some posts mention that I need memcached instead of memcache, which is newer and the error asks me for the memcached class. I found this memcached package instead: pecl.php.net/package/memcached/3.0.4 ........and it has a memcached-api.php file which has the memcached class in it, but it also has other files and I the readme file only stays that I must install libmemcached but still unclear

Comment: You are using XAMPP does that not show you the PHP version on the Manager windows

Comment: I have a control panel but it doesn't show. I found the version on the page I downloaded xampp from and it's: PHP 7.2.7

Comment: So did you down load the `php_memcache.dll` that was compiled for `PHP7.2` and also it should be the `_ts_` one

Comment: So what do I have to do about this? I am not sure how to check if the dll is the correct one or to find the right one. I also don't know what ts is. Will googling help me find the right dll file?